# PopUpMenuButton not working in listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i've tring to call a method for showing popupmenubutton in listview, but i dont know wht its not working and doesnt show the popmenu.

here is my code :

```
List<String> menuDropdown = ["Publish", "Bagikan", "Hapus"];
  String dropdownSelect;

  void selectMenu(context) {
    PopupMenuButton<String>(
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        return menuDropdown.map((e) {
          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
              value: e,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  e,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Warnaku.hitam),
                ),
              ));
        }).toList();
      },
      onSelected: (e) {
        dropdownSelect = e;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: you are creating a new `PopupMenuButton` and not using it anywhere inside `selectMenu()` method

Comment: @pskink so i cant use popmenubutton on any widget in listview?

Comment: I never tried that before but I don't see any reason why you couldn't use it

Comment: @pskink is your code work when call PopUpMenuButton in listview?

Comment: `class FooList extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: 32,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title: Text('item #$index'),
trailing: PopupMenuButton<int>(
onSelected: (i) {
print('selected $i for item $index');
},
itemBuilder: (context) => [
PopupMenuItem(child: Text('1st action'), value: 0,),
PopupMenuItem(child: Text('2nd action'), value: 1,),
PopupMenuItem(child: Text('3rd action'), value: 2,),
],
),
);
},
);
}
}`

Comment: @pskink my stupid, i was thinking if popupmenubutton is method, it's a widget. thanks bro

Comment: sure, your welcome